# Partial derivative notation

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative

Suppose $F(x,y,z)=x+y+z$. Then the partial derivative of $F$ w.r.t. $x$ is $1$. (Most books don't mention that $y$ and $z$ are held constants and it's sort of implied.) But what if $z$ was a function of $x$? If $z=x$, then $F=2x+y$. In that case the answer should have been $2$. So what does the partial derivative w.r.t. $x$ mean? Do I always require a prior knowledge of the nature of the arguments $x$,$y$,$z$ in order to take partial derivatives?

Answer (score 1):

> The  representation $$F(x,y,z)$$  does  not indicate that a variable  is  a  function of another variable.  If  so, it has   to  be  stated and is often explicitly written as in
>   \begin{align*}
> F(x,y,z(x))
> \end{align*}

The partial derivative is then to calculate accordingly.